# Move a Core Data entity and its data into new Core Data model file through Migration

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

Is it possible to move a Core Data entity `Car` and its data in `Model1` into a new Core Data model `Model2` using migration? `Model2` will also have a new `CarOwner` entity + other new relationships (so model file is different than `Model1`). Is this possible using lightweight migration or do I have to use custom migration? I'm using Magical Record to setup my Core Data Stack.

I have been using lightweight migration for years with success. So I don't have any custom migration mechanism in place. I want to ask first before I implement a new system so I can incorporate CD custom migration into my existing MagicalRecord Core Data stack.

*EDIT: updated question to clarify that `Model1` and `Model2` have differences.*

Answer (score 0):

With the same xcdatamodel file and different versions you can use a Mapping Model file, but being different mom files i guess those are different stacks and migration will not work.

Comment: So will this be possible using custom migration?

Comment: @Buju i don't think so. Why you need 2 different mom if you don't want them to be really separate?

Comment: because `Model1` is has already many versions. some of them have warnings. and `Model1` structure is already very old. Now I need to migrate all the existing data into a new much bigger, more modern `Model2`. I want to start `Model2` with model version 1 again.

Comment: But the main point is, I want to get rid of the old versions which produced warnings. And I have multiple (old) model files, which I want to merge all into `Model2`.

Comment: after extensive research, it turns out that it is possible to migrate entities from one model file into another file using custom mapping model `.xcmappingmodel` and custom migration.

Comment: @Buju i tested using a sample project but Xcode 7 produced some warnings and with Xcode 6 i created a second xcdatamodel file but with no Entity and xcmappingmodel had invalid source/destination. I tested again now with both xcdatamodel files populated with entities and seems to work, now i can select source and destination to in the mapping model file. There is a book "Pro Core Data" where you have a chapter on custom migrations, i guess that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Model migration is only relevant if the model has changed-- meaning, if the entities contained in the data model don't match the entities saved in the persistent store file. Migration doesn't depend on what model file you use, it depends on the entity hashes contained in that model.

Meaning: If your new model file has **exactly the same entities** as the persistent store file has, you don't actually need to migrate anything. Just start using the new model file. **However** keep in mind that if you ditch the old model file and all of its old versions, you won't be able to migrate from *older versions* of that model any more.

Comment: thats the point. I need to keep all older versions, so all my users can still migrate to the latest version. And the model doesn't stay the same. It changes, so I definitely need a migration.

Comment: So... what is the point of moving to a new model file then? In comments on @Lucien's answer you talked about all the problems with `Model1` that you wanted to get rid of. I really don't know what you're hoping to accomplish any more.

Comment: ok to be more precise: `Model1` is currently only in an app. But now I need to move my model file into a (shared) library so other apps can use the same model file `Model2`. And for that reason `Model2` is highly enhanced with other entities and new relationships. So app1 needs to migrate data from `Model1` to `Model2`. but another new app will then start using the shared library with `Model2` so app2 will not get all the warnings from `Model1`. I didn't explain this because what I want is exactly what I ask in my question. Migrate entity to another Core Data model file.